# How to find redirected url using requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm building a web scraper using Python and found a page which redirects to another page after displaying some text on screen. I'm using the `requests` library. How can I find the URL it redirects to?

display message like (page1)

```
wait we will redirect you...
```

`r.content` displays the source code of page 1. How to wait for the last page to load? It gets redirected through 2-3 pages.

Comment: A "redirected url" and "a page which redirects to another page after ..." are not the same thing.  If you are talking about a proper url redirect, that is within the realm of `requests` and doesn't directly have anything to do with beautifulsoup.  If you are talking about a web-page that loads another page after some time, please link that page for others to read as its contents is important to your question

Comment: Always bear in mind that [Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files.](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).  It doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the actual user-flow of a given website as a whole, it is extracting data from static documents.

Comment: The page redirects to another page after sometime using javascript.